# JupyterLab doesn't run due to AssertionError

Tags: linux, python, pop-os, jupyterlab

I have used [pip to install JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/install) on my machine that runs Pop!_OS. The installation succeeds, but when I attempt to run the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foof/.local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/home/foof/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.application import JupyterApp, NoStart, base_aliases, base_flags
  File "/home/foof/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from traitlets import Bool, List, Unicode, observe
  File "/home/foof/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._version import __version__, version_info
  File "/home/foof/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/_version.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert __version__ == (
AssertionError
```

I have reinstalled Python and pip but always get the same error. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is to [change the traitlets](https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/pull/739) version by editing

```
~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/_version.py
```

to read:

```
version_info = (5, 2, 2)
__version__ = "5.2.2"
```